# If one cell is equal to any of the cell in a coloumn,

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

If A1 cell is equal to the value in B column, the result should be A2 cell, if A2 cell also equal to the value in B column then result should be A3.

Please show me the Formula.

Comment: Could you put a picture in your post. The question is unclear to me.

Comment: A B     
1 252 150 =IF(A1=(B1:B9),A2,A1) And IF(A2 also =B1:B9),A3,A1)    
2 141 654     
  984     
  784     
  525     
  141     
  981     
  710     
  252

Comment: Okay, and what happens if A1 is not in B column?

Comment: If A1 is not in B column it should be blank.

Comment: =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,B:B,1,0)),"",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,B:B,1,0)),A2,A3)).. This is the Formula I was expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,B:B,1,0)),"",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,B:B,1,0)),A2,A3))
```

From what I understood:

- If A1 is not in column B, it should return blank.
- Otherwise, when A1 is in column B:

  - If A2 is not in column B, then take A2 else,
  - If A2 is in column E, then take A3.

`VLOOKUP` is being used to check if A1 is in column B:B. `A1=B:B` can be used, but it will mean that you will be dealing with an array formula, which is not necessary here as you can see (and which will make your formula more complex).

`ISERROR` is the check for whether there was a match of not. You see, VLOOKUP returns `#N/A!` when there is no match.

Comment: Dear, Your Formula is Fine. But when A1 is not available it gives 0. It should be blank.

Comment: @user2912097 Can you take a screenshot and upload the picture? I don't see how this formula can return 0. It will return either blank, the value from A2 or that from A3.

Comment: A B C
150 150 0
 654 
 984

Comment: @user2912097 Upload a picture [here](http://tinypic.com/) and post the link please. It's impossible to read that.

Comment: Dear, I cannot upload a picture, asking for reputations. how can I paste a excel format?

Comment: @user2912097 You don't need reputation to upload a picture. Just take a screenshot, put it on the site I linked above and share the link. There's no paste excel format.

Comment: Ok dear, I got it. In your formula u have mentioned 0. I changed to "" this. Now it works good. Thank u vey much. I hope your help in future also

Comment: @user2912097 If your questions are clear, then you will surely get help, and not only from me. You cannot directly put a picture in your posts, but you can put the link to the picture like I told you how and it will often make your questions clearer, since pictures are said to be worth 1000 words, okay? Feel free to mark my answer as accepted. You'll get some rep too until you have enough to directly put a picture.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this? :
( SI = IF in english ).
Colum c have this formula respectly.
[image]

Comment: Dear, how did u put this image? please help. i'll be able ask my questions easily.